# Why do I need to specify the XML namespace when using getAttributeResourceValue?

Tags: android

I've been using custom attributes for some custom layout components without problem. So far, I've only used simple attributes (string, int, etc). These are defined like so in `values/attrs.xml`:

```
<declare-styleable name="StaticListView">
    <attr name="border_size" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

and in my layout:

```
<de.example.androidapp.StaticListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        namespace:border_size="1px"
   />
```

and used like so:

```
int borderSize = (int) a.getDimension(R.styleable.StaticListView_border_size, 0);
```

Now, I'm trying to specify a layout as a custom attribute and am not able to use the `R.styleable` method used above.

Here's how I'm defining the attribute:

```
<declare-styleable name="StaticListView">
    <attr name="emptyLayout" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

and using it:

```
<de.example.androidapp.StaticListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        namespace:emptyLayout="@layout/empty"
   />
```

And this is how I would like to use it, but I always get the default value (`-1`):

```
int emptyLayoutInt = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(R.styleable.StaticListView_emptyLayout, -1);
```

This, however, works:

```
int emptyLayoutInt = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/de.example.androidapp", "emptyLayout", -1);
```

I dislike having to hardcode the XML namespace. Using the `R.styleable` attribute avoids this in a nice way.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug/expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the line :

```
int emptyLayoutInt = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(R.styleable.StaticListView_emptyLayout, -1);
```

Use this -

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.MyLayout);
    int layoutId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyLayout_text,-1);
```

The -1 is getting returned because the value is not available in the attr set.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't solve my problem, but it did lead me to look again at the `TypedArray` instance that I wasn't using correctly.

Comment: Welcome :) I forgot to write getResourceId. I am making the final changes in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. I was going through the `AttributeSet` variable `attrs`, because for some reason, but I should have been using the `TypedArray` instance like I do with the rest of the attributes. Here's the line of code that works:

```
int emptyLayoutInt = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.StaticGridView_emptyLayout, -1);
```